# Not getting the right result using XPath with python scraper

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get some information of some specific website using python Scraper, namely some links to some products. The website I am looking at is http://www.ah.nl/producten/verse-kant-en-klaar-maaltijden-salades The links I am looking for are the following
[image]

If one goes to this website and inspects for example the element "Maaltijdsalades", then you can see that the links are under //ul/li using XPath syntax. The problem is that in that same HTML code, there is another place where //ul/li is used for links I am not looking for. I used the following spider and it crawls exactly the links which I do not want.

I am using the following spider

```
import scrapy

from ah_links.items import AhLinksItem

class AhSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ah_links"
    allowed_domains = ["ah.nl"]
    start_urls=['http://www.ah.nl/producten/aardappel-groente-fruit', 
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = AhLinksItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

I need help on solving this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you should search for the list inside the sub categories block:

```
for sel in response.css('nav.subcategorynav li'):
    item = AhLinksItem()
    item['title'] = sel.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
    yield item
```

Here I'm using a CSS selector, but you can also solve it with an XPath:

```
response.xpath('//nav[contains(@class, "subcategorynav")]//li')
```

Comment: The links I am looking for are indeed under //nav[@class="subcategorynav"]. If I use this XPath (or the CSS selector), I don't get any result. Do you know why?

Comment: @Badshah got it, debugged a little bit and updated the answer. Should work, try it out.

Comment: It worked with the CSS selector! Thank you, but it doesn't work with XPath though...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
item['title'] = sel.xpath("./a/@href").extract()
```

Edited, this works as expected

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
response = requests.get("http://www.ah.nl/producten/aardappel-groente-fruit")
parsed_response = fromstring(response.text)
for item in parsed_response.xpath(".//ul/li"):
    print item.xpath("a/@href")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't help either. Why would the point help, if I may ask?